# Using sqlite3 for dev and postgres on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am creating a node-application that will be deployed to prod. To make it easy to setup the dev-enviroment I want to use sqlite3 locally - and postgres when I deploy to heroku.

The node-sqlite3 and node-postgres packages seem to have a bit different API - so it seems I would need an extra layer of abstraction to switch between the two engines.

Is there a easy way to switch between postgres an sqlite on node-apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For these kinds of problems you seem to have 2 solutions:

1. Using am ORM that supports both engines, like [sequalize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/)
2. Use the same engine for both development and production.

   - For projects with multiple members you can easely setuo enviroment using thins like [docker](https://www.docker.com/) or [vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/).

For my projects I went with the 2nd option, and setup a devenviroment in Vagrant to be shared with all the team-members.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ORM, for example,  [sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/)